# MySQL says "Unexpected Identifier" and "missing /"

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and just downloaded it and am trying to execute things into the command line

I typed in

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
```

and responded with

> Unexpected Identifier

After looking for why I realized that it was defaulting to JS and people said to type `/sql` into the command line.
After I tried that it responded with

```
missing /
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more specific details. It's not clear what you're trying and what is specifically not working without more details about your environment.

Comment: Where are you typing these commands?

Comment: If you're in a JS console, `/` is the beginning of a regular expression.

Comment: You need to type `mysql` from the command prompt.